# Button array in VB.NET

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net, button, matrix

I have this PHP file that communicates with a server. The file requires two variables from the VB.NET program, the coordinates x,y.

I've managed to generate a 32x32 matrix of buttons. Each button should send the PHP file the two variables which are strings. Let's say the first row has as y="001" and the 32 buttons of that row x = "001", "002", etc.

I've obviously got a function that does the sending, but how do I tell that for the first row you should send y="001" and based on the button of that row his x which goes from 001 to 032.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class frmButton
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    ' Declaring array of (1024) Buttons
    Private btnArray(1024) As System.Windows.Forms.Button

    'Funzione che invia sorgente e destinazione al file PHP
    Public Function inviaphp(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As String
        Dim strReq As String
        Dim strData As String
        Dim dataStream As Stream
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim request As WebRequest
        Dim response As WebResponse
        Dim src As String = x
        Dim dest As String = y
        strReq = "http://localhost/Matrice_PHPVBNET/R1/prova1.php?src=" & src & "&&dest=" & dest
        request = WebRequest.Create(strReq)
        response = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        strData = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
    End Function

    Private Sub AddButtons()
        Dim xPos As Integer = 0
        Dim yPos As Integer = -20
        Dim n As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1023
            ' Initialize one variable
            btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Next i

        While (n < 1024)
            With (btnArray(n))
                .Tag = n + 1 ' Tag of button
                .Width = 24 ' Width of button
                .Height = 20 ' Height of button
                If (n Mod 32 = 0) Then ' Location of buttons:
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos += 20

                End If
                ' Location of button:
                .Left = xPos
                .Top = yPos
                ' Add buttons to a Panel:
                pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnArray(n)) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
                xPos = xPos + .Width
                AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Me.ClickButton
                n += 1
            End With
        End While

        btnAddButton.Enabled = False ' No need now to this button now
        label1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    ' Result of (Click Button) event, get the text of button
    Public Sub ClickButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
        Dim btn As Button
        Dim x As String = "000"
        Dim y() As String = {"000", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013",
            "014", "015", "016", "017", "018", "019", "020", "021", "022", "023", "024", "025", "026", "027", "028", "029", "030", "031",
            "032"}
        Dim j As Integer = 32
        'For i As Integer = 1 To 1024
        'If (i <= j) Then
        'inviaphp(x, y(i))
        'End If
        ' Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddButton.Click
        AddButtons()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub pnlButtons_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pnlButtons.Paint

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmButton_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

I usually code in C++. Can I do something like this in VB.NET?

```
void btn(button btnarray(), int d)
{
    char y;
    char x()={"001","002""0xx","032"};
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        if(i<=32)
        {
            btnarray(i).click=
            y="001";
            inviaphp(y,x(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and have if's for all 32 row?

Final working code thanks to DrDonut:

```
Public Class frmButton



    'Funzione che invia sorgente e destinazione al file PHP
    Public Function inviaphp(ByVal comand As String) As Object
        Dim strReq As String
        Dim strData As String
        Dim dataStream As Stream
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim request As WebRequest
        Dim response As WebResponse
        strReq = "http://localhost/Matrice_PHPVBNET/R1/prova1.php?comand=" & comand
        request = WebRequest.Create(strReq)
        response = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        strData = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
    End Function

    Private Sub AddButtons()
        Dim xPos As Integer = 0
        Dim yPos As Integer = -20
        Dim n As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1023
            ' Initialize one variable
            btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Next i

        While (n < 1024)
            With (btnArray(n))
                .Tag = n + 1 ' Tag of button
                .Width = 24 ' Width of button
                .Height = 20 ' Height of button
                If (n Mod 32 = 0) Then ' Location of buttons:
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos += 20

                End If
                ' Location of button:
                .Left = xPos
                .Top = yPos
                ' Add buttons to a Panel:
                pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnArray(n)) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
                xPos = xPos + .Width
                AddHandler .Click, AddressOf ClickButton
                n += 1
            End With
        End While

        For row As Integer = 0 To 31
            For col As Integer = 0 To 31
                btnArray(row * 32 + col).Name = (row + 1).ToString("D3") + (col + 1).ToString("D3")
            Next
        Next

        btnAddButton.Enabled = False ' not need now to this button now
        label1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    ' Result of (Click Button) event, get the text of button
    Public Sub ClickButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
        Dim row As String = sender.name.subString(0, 3)
        Dim col As String = sender.name.subString(3, 3)
        MsgBox(sender.name)
        Dim comando As String = row + "," + col
        inviaphp(comando)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddButton.Click
        AddButtons()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub pnlButtons_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pnlButtons.Paint

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmButton_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: a) What have you tried? b) Maybe similar to what you're doing in `AddButtons`? The buttons are "ordered/numbered" via the `.tag` property, x equals btn.tag mod 32 and y equals btn.tag / 32. Or c) put the buttons in some grid container and then ask that container where the event source object is located within it.

Comment: I usually code in c++ and even there i'm a noob. Can you elaborate, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you have to put the coördinates of the button in the button itself, so it can send it when it's clicked. Assuming that your buttons are Windows Forms Buttons, you can use the `name` field of the buttons:

```
for row as integer = 0 to 31
    for col as integer = 0 to 31
        btnArray(row*32+col).name = (row+1).ToString("D3") + (col+1).ToString("D3")
    end for
end for
```

You can add this code right after the loop where you make your button array.

This code sets the `name` property of the button to rowColumn. Example: A button at row 14, column 5 would get the name: 014005. Because both the row and the column are always written as 3 digits (the 'D3' argument in the ToString method), it is easy to filter where you read the button.

This way all the names are set to: `00x00y`.

In your clickButton function, the `sender` object is the button, so you can extract the position by:

```
dim row as integer = Convert.toInt32(sender.name.subString(0,3))
dim col as integer = Convert.toInt32(sender.name.subString(3,3))
```

Comment: first of all thank for asnwering and sencond: where do i put this code and can you please explain the logic behind this so i can understand better

Comment: @RachetRacoon, see the modified answer.

Comment: if i do MsgBox(sender.name) the first button from the first row shows 000000, i don't need the row zero and the zero button. how can i do ?

Comment: @RachetRacoon, see modified code. The row and col numbers need to start at 0, because the array in which the buttons are located is zero based, so just cosmetically increment the number.